# Get Image for Wishlist product in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

To get wishlist items for customer I use the code

```
    $wishlist = $this->wishlistFactory->create()->loadByCustomerId($customerId);
    if (!$wishlist->getId()) {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Customer does not yet have a wishlist', null, 1));
    }
    $wishlist['items'] = $wishlist->getItemCollection()->getItems();
```

it returns array

"items": [
{
"wishlist_item_id": 726664,
"wishlist_id": 177822,
"product_id": 6412,
"store_id": 1,
"added_at": "2022-08-10 10:45:21",
"qty": 1,
"product_name": "Item Name",
"price": 53.99
}

but it returns items without image. What is the way to get items with the Image Url link?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

First add items in a variable like below -

```
$items = $wishlist->getItemCollection()->getItems();
```

I think the above $items gives you all items of wishlist so to get one wishlist item use foreach loop.

then with the help of object manager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$Storemanager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$mediaUrl = $Storemanager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```

use image tag as below -

```
<img width="135" height="135" src="<?= $mediaUrl.'catalog/product'.$item->getProduct()->getThumbnail(); ?>">
```

I recommend to add these code in Block file and then call function of Block in phtml file instead of using direct objectmanager.

Hope it helps!!